# how to apply window function in memory transformation with new column scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which I want to transform as below output where each row start_duration and end_duration will be resulted from previous row start_duration and end_duration, please let me know how to achieve it in spark using scala.

Below is the formulae to calculate start_duration and end_duration :

```
start_duration = max(previous end_duration + 1, current date); 
end_duration = min(presciption_end date, start_duration + duration – 1)
```

Below is my input data frame :

```
+--------

--------+-----------+---------+-----------+----------------+----------+--------+----------+----------+
|prescription_uid|patient_uid|ndc      |label      |dispensation_uid|date      |duration|start_date|end_date  |
+----------------+-----------+---------+-----------+----------------+----------+--------+----------+----------+
|0               |0          |16714-128|sinvastatin|0               |2015-06-10|30      |2015-06-01|2015-12-01|
|0               |0          |16714-128|sinvastatin|1               |2015-07-15|30      |2015-06-01|2015-12-01|
|0               |0          |16714-128|sinvastatin|2               |2015-08-01|30      |2015-06-01|2015-12-01|
|0               |0          |16714-128|sinvastatin|3               |2015-10-01|30      |2015-06-01|2015-12-01|
+----------------+-----------+---------+-----------+----------------+----------+--------+----------+----------+
```

Expected Output Data frame :

```
EXPECTED RESULT:
    +--------
    
        --------+-----------+---------+-----------+----------------+----------+--------+----------+----------+--------------------+------------------+--------------+------------+
        |prescription_uid|patient_uid|ndc      |label      |dispensation_uid|date      |duration|start_date|end_date  |first_start_duration|first_end_duration|start_duration|end_duration|
        +----------------+-----------+---------+-----------+----------------+----------+--------+----------+----------+--------------------+------------------+--------------+------------+
        |0               |0          |16714-128|sinvastatin|0               |2015-06-10|30      |2015-06-01|2015-12-01|2015-06-10          |2015-07-09        |2015-06-10    |2015-07-09  |
        |0               |0          |16714-128|sinvastatin|1               |2015-07-15|30      |2015-06-01|2015-12-01|2015-06-10          |2015-07-09        |2015-07-15    |2015-08-13  |
        |0               |0          |16714-128|sinvastatin|2               |2015-08-01|30      |2015-06-01|2015-12-01|2015-06-10          |2015-07-09        |2015-08-14    |2015-09-13  |
        |0               |0          |16714-128|sinvastatin|3               |2015-10-01|30      |2015-06-01|2015-12-01|2015-06-10          |2015-07-09        |2015-10-01    |2015-10-30  |
        +----------------+-----------+---------+-----------+----------------+----------+--------+----------+----------+--------------------+------------------+--------------+------------+
    
Code tried : 
val windowByPatient = Window.partitionBy($"patient_uid").orderBy($"date")
    val windowByPatientBeforeCurrentRow = windowByPatient.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)
    joinedPrDF = joinedPrDF
      .withColumn("first_start_duration", firstStartDuration(first($"date").over(windowByPatient), $"start_date"))
      .withColumn("first_end_duration", firstEndDuration($"first_start_duration", $"end_date", $"duration"))
      .withColumn("start_duration", when(count("*").over(windowByPatient) === 1, $"first_start_duration")
        .otherwise(startDurationCalc($"first_start_duration", $"date", $"start_date", coalesce(sum($"duration").over(windowByPatientBeforeCurrentRow), lit("0")))))
      .withColumn("end_duration", when(count("*").over(windowByPatient) === 1, $"first_end_duration")
        .otherwise(endDurationCalc($"end_date", $"start_duration", $"duration")))
```

UDF :

```
val startDurationCalc = udf( (firstStrtDur:java.sql.Date, currentDsDate:java.sql.Date,
                                      prsStartDate:java.sql.Date,duration:Int) => {
      println("==="+firstStrtDur+"==="+currentDsDate +"==="+prsStartDate +"==="+duration )

        var startDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(firstStrtDur.toLocalDate.plusDays(duration))
        if (startDate.after(currentDsDate)) {
          startDate
        } else {
          currentDsDate
        }
    } : java.sql.Date)

    val endDurationCalc = udf( (prsEndDate:java.sql.Date, startDuration:java.sql.Date,duration:Int) => {

      println("endDateCalcContRow ==="+prsEndDate+"==="+startDuration +"==="+duration )

      val currEndDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(startDuration.toLocalDate.plusDays(duration-1))
      if (currEndDate.before(prsEndDate)) {
        currEndDate
      } else {
        prsEndDate
      }

    } : java.sql.Date)
```

Comment: can you please post code for ```startDateCalcContRow``` & ```endDateCalcContRow```

Comment: posted code for both udf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the final start duration calculator using lag window function on previous duration and previous dispensation date :

```
val startDurationCalc = udf((currentDsDate: java.sql.Date, prevDsDate: java.sql.Date, prevDuration: Int, prsEndDate: java.sql.Date,
                                 firstStrtDur:java.sql.Date,acDuration:Int) => {
      println("startDurationCalc===currentDsDate===" + currentDsDate + "===prevDsDate===" + prevDsDate +
        "===prevDuration===" + prevDuration +"===prsEndDate==="+prsEndDate+"===firstStrtDur=="+firstStrtDur+"===acDuration==="+acDuration)
      val prevDurStartDate = prevDsDate.toLocalDate.plusDays(prevDuration - 1)
      var derivedDsDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(prevDurStartDate.plusDays(1))
      val accumulatedDSDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(firstStrtDur.toLocalDate.plusDays(acDuration))

      if (derivedDsDate.before(accumulatedDSDate)) {
        derivedDsDate = accumulatedDSDate
      }

      if (derivedDsDate.after(prsEndDate)) {
        val derPrsEndDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(prsEndDate.toLocalDate.plusDays(1))
        derPrsEndDate
      } else {
        if (currentDsDate.after(derivedDsDate)) {
          currentDsDate
        } else {
          derivedDsDate
        }
      }
    }: java.sql.Date).asNondeterministic()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not expect window functions to make computation on data not present in dataframe, but computed during execution (you called it "in memory rows"). It is not possible.

You can try different approach. Compute each `start_duration` form the first one, based on `duration` (you can take into account possible gaps).

```
val windowByPatient = Window.partitionBy("patient_uid").orderBy("date")
val windowByPatientBeforeCurrentRow = windowByPatient.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)

data
  .withColumn("previous_date", lag("date", 1).over(windowByPatient))
  .withColumn("diff_from_prev", datediff(col("date"), coalesce(col("previous_date"), col("date"))))
  .withColumn("diff_with_duration", when(col("diff_from_prev") >= lag("duration", 1, 0).over(windowByPatient), col("diff_from_prev")).otherwise(col("duration")))
  .withColumn("first_date_by_patient", first("date").over(windowByPatient))
  .withColumn("duration_from_first_with_gaps", col("diff_with_duration") + coalesce(sum("diff_from_prev").over(windowByPatientBeforeCurrentRow), lit("0")))
  .withColumn("start_duration", expr("date_add(first_date_by_patient, duration_from_first_with_gaps)"))
  .withColumn("end_duration", expr("date_add(start_duration, duration - 1)"))
  .select((data.columns ++ Seq("start_duration", "end_duration")).map(col): _*)
  .show()
```

`date_add` is wrapped in `expr`, because it takes `Int` as second argument, but can be used with column in sql context.

Comment: Yes, end_duration is equal to "start_duration + duration -1", I compute it with `date_add(start_duration, diff_in_days)` where diff_in_days = `col("duration") - 1`

Comment: For your example data result in last row should be: 
`start_duration = 2015-09-08, end_duration = 2015-10-07`

Comment: @SanjeevThakur I have posted output from my solution, I think it is exactly what you have expected

Comment: if there is a gap in middle then adding duration to first start duration will not work.

Comment: what do you mean by gap, can you post an example?

Comment: updated main post with gap in second row and last row.

Comment: did you understood issue with solution you proposed ?

Comment: I have updated my answer, assumption is the same, just changed how the difference from first date is computed